# mysql variables between two queries

Tags: mysql

I need execute this query:

```
SELECT MAX(col1) FROM table1;
INSERT INTO table1 (col1) VALUES (@someting);
```

Where @something is `MAX(col1) + 1`.
Can you help me writing queries? I need query works also with NULL values...I think I need a CAST.

This is a drupal like table. col0 is AUTO_INCREMENT, but col1 can't for a lot of reasons.

col0 is the primary key and auto_increment is active. But I use vid as versioning ID. I need to increment this without insert new records and I need a thread-safe query.

Comment: Is this a homegrown (and non-threadsafe!) implementation of [`auto_increment`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html)? If so, just use `auto_increment` instead.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a variable for this. You can just use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`  statement:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1)
  SELECT MAX(col1) + 1 FROM table1
```

If you need this to work by returning 1 if `MAX(col1)` is `NULL`, use a `COALESCE()`:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1)
  SELECT COLAESCE(MAX(col1) + 1, 1) FROM table1
```

Note: as mentioned in the comments, if you are attempting to make an incrementing column, don't do this. Use a proper `AUTO_INCREMENT` instead which will be safe from race conditions.

#### Update after comments:

What you have in the comments is significantly different from your question.  Your syntax there is invalid and should not have a `VALUES()` keyword and parenthetical group.  Instead, do it as:

```
INSERT INTO node (vid, type, uid, title, created, changed, status, promote, sticky)
  SELECT
    COALESCE(MAX(vid) + 1, 1),
    'node',
    1,
    'title', 
    1,1,1,1,1
  FROM node
```

A proper auto-incrementing column definition for `vid` would look like the following, assuming it is the primary key:

```
vid INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Using the above, there would be no need to do `MAX(vid) + 1`

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work: 
INSERT INTO node
(vid, type, uid, title, created, changed, status, promote, sticky)
VALUES
(SELECT MAX(id) FROM node, "node", 1, "title", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

And then I need to check for NULL values too.

Comment: @Admdebian The query in your comment has `VALUES( ... )` in it. That isn't what the answer has. Read carefully.

Comment: QUERY: INSERT INTO node
(vid, type, uid, title, created, changed, status, promote, sticky)
VALUES
(SELECT COLAESCE(MAX(vid) + 1, 1) FROM node, "node", 1, "title", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);

ERROR:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT COLAESCE(MAX(vid) + 1, 1) FROM node, "node", 1, "title", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)' at line 4

Comment: @Admdebian Look at my query. There is no `VALUES()`.  The `SELECT` comes immediately following the `INSERT INTO ()`

Comment: @Admdebian Your code is not thread-safe. With enough traffic you will have collisions for values in the `vid` column. Better (and easier!) to use [`auto_increment`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html). That's what it's for.

Comment: @Asaph col0 is the primary key and auto_increment is active. But I use vid as versioning ID. I need to increment this without insert new record and in a thread-safe query.

Comment: I solved all my troubles! From INSERT to Update, all of that. Thanks to all! I solved last doubt with: update node SET vid = vid +1 where nid = 1;